# Building HTML table in javascript, getting "ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope someone can help me out with this.  I'm trying to dynamically build an HTML table in javascript/jquery based on iterating over an array built by earlier code.  I am getting an error on the referenced line below as soon as the page loads:

```
function BuildForm (allFields) {
    var dyndata = "";
    var formstart = "<form>\n<fieldset class='fieldset-js'>\n<legend>Choose A Parent</legend>\n<table class='table-js'>\n<tr>\n<th class='th'>ID</th>\n<th class='th'>Name</th>\n<th class='th'>DOB</th>\n<th class='th'>Phone</th>\n</tr>\n<tr>";
    $('#PickAParent-Form').append(formstart);
    $.each(allFields, function (index, value) {
        if ((index + 5) % 5 == 0) {
            dyndata = "<tr>\n<td class='td1'><input type='radio' name='pid' value='" = index + "'>" + value + "</td>\n";
     error here---------^
            $('#PickAParent-Form').append(dyndata);
        } elseif ((index +1 ) % 5 == 0) {
            dyndata = "<td class='td1'>" + value + "</td>\n</tr>\n";
            $('#PickAParent-Form').append(dyndata);
        } else {
            dyndata = "<td class='td1'>" + value + "</td>\n";
            $('#PickAParent-Form').append(dyndata);
        }
    });
    DisplayForm;
}
```

I have been all over Google and SO this AM but can't figure this one out.  Any help is MUCH appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
dyndata = "<tr>\n<td class='td1'><input type='radio' name='pid' value='" = index + "'>" + value + "</td>\n";
```

should be:

```
dyndata = "<tr>\n<td class='td1'><input type='radio' name='pid' value='" + index + "'>" + value + "</td>\n";
```

Looks like you had an equals sign instead of a plus sign for variable to string conversion

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you so much - I looked that code over multiple times and never saw that "=" there instead of a "+".  Appreciate the assist!!

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
dyndata = "<tr>\n<td class='td1'><input type='radio' name='pid' value='" + index + "'>" + value + "</td>\n";
```

Note:

```
value='" + index + "'
```

Instead of:

```
value='" = index + "'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help as well.  You were spot on, but Codemonk beat you to it... :)